# Basic sewing machine

Tags: sewing-machine

I am looking for a basic sewing machine.

I do not need any "bells or whistles."

I was in a sewing machine shop and they showed me some Brother machines.

Cheapest was around $500.

I do not need 26 varieties of stitches and able to store programs.

Here are my wishes.

1. Able to wind the bobbin
2. Be able to stitch heavier fabrics like denim
3. Use generic items such as bobbins, needles, etc.

   Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about product recommendations are off topic on the site.

Comment: As per: https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/where-is-the-line-between-material-selection-and-product-recommendations

Comment: True, we can't really give a specific answer to this. I've closed as a duplicate of another question that covers some characteristics to look for when shopping for sewing machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our local Craigslist has dozens of sewing machines, many under one hundred US dollars. Even the lowest cost one that appeared in my search has seventeen different stitches.

The features you require are likely to be found on most of these used machines, although the heavy fabric requirement could mean you have to be more focused with your research.

Yard sales and flea markets will also have the occasional sewing machine. I frequent a local flea market on a regular basis and have seen a couple "old-school" sewing machines in good condition.